# ReactJs Functional Component | File Input | With Form | Upload Image like the Laravel way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, react-hooks

I have this **ReactJs** form using **Laravel React ui scaffolding**. How can I upload an image with other input on my form?

**AddProduct.js**

```
...
const AddProduct = () => {
  
  *//state*
  const initialProductState = {
    id: null,
    image: "",
    category_id: "1",
    name: "",
  };
  const [product,setProduct] = useState(initialProductState);
  ...

  *//handle controlled input change*
  const handleInputChange = event => {
    const {name,value} = event.target;
    setProduct({...product, [name]:value });
  }
  
  *// handle file input change*
  const handleFileChange = (event) => {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    console.log(file);
  }
  
  *//Form Submit*
  const onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let data = {
      category_id: product.category_id,
      image: product.image,
      name: product.name
    };
    console.log(data);

    axios.post(`/api/products`,data)
    .then(response => {
       setProduct({...})
    })
    .catch(e=>{
       console.log(e)
    });

    ... *proceed to return*
```

**AddForm.js**

```
return (
  <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    <select id="category_id" name="category_id" onChange={...}>...</select>
    <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} value={product.image}/>
    <input type="text" value={...} onChange={...}/>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
)
```

As we can see on the code that I initially declare a state that includes all of the inputs. Now, the questions.

1. How can I set the name of the image in the file input value?
2. How can I include the image together with other form inputs? - I've seen some tutorials on how to upload an image but they only focus on the file input alone.
3. Is there any conversion that I might encounter?
4. What is the correct way of declaring **onChange** for the file input?